# Electron app can't display image from oepnweatheramp api link

Tags: html, node.js, npm, electron

This is my code that is used to generate icon code from OpenWeatherMap API

```
fetch(
  "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" +
    name +
    "&appid=" +
    API_KEY
)
  .then((response) => response.json())
  .then((response) => {
    const icon = response.weather[0].icon;

    //These are the various solutions I have try, but still doesn't work

    document
      .querySelector("#wicon")
      .attributes("src", "openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png");
    document
      .querySelector("#wicon")
      .getAttribute("src", "openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png");
    $("#wicon").attr("src", "openweathermap.org/img/w/" + icon + ".png");
  });
```

I experiment to see if the weather icon code can display by return the icon as an innerText, it works fine.

and if I put the same link insert src in HTML is will work

Answer (score 1):

you don't need any helpers just set attribute `src` on `HTMLElement`

```js
document
    .querySelector("#wicon")
    .src = "https://picsum.photos/400/200";
```

```html
<img id="wicon" />
```

Comment: the weather icon is not for a specific region and is always changing, that's where the major problem is

Comment: sure, you can set whatever url, just specify protocol `https://` and use setter `.src = string`